# Use the auto-generated objectId or create your own Unique ID for mapping classes in Parse

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json, parse-platform

We want to bulk upload data to our mobile backend in [Parse](https://parse.com/). We have two classes :- Store and Product. One store can have multiple products whereas one product can only belong to one store. Now we want to bulk upload products & stores with a CSV / JSON upload.

To do this, according to our research we have two options :-

1. Use the JSON importer to import objects where we define the ObjectId for both classes manually according to are own IDs.
2. Create another column for a unique productId and storeId in each class. First upload stores, then upload products where we first lookup the randomly generated objectId for each store using the storeId and use that to generate our pointer in the product class.

Which one is a better option? Are there any drawbacks to manually generating your own objectId?

Answer (score 1):

On the Parse support there is a mention about [the risks of having duplicate IDs on a specific class](https://parse.com/questions/is-objectid-unique-for-the-class-or-for-the-whole-pfobjects):

> Note that you'll need billions of objects before you have even a slight chance of having a duplicate. So you can probably assume that it will not happen. We simply don't enforce it when we generate it.

So I think it's reasonable to assume that you can generate your own `objectId`'s when importing and that will have the same safety/performance as an automatically generated one.